# Parse SubscriptionHandling handleEvents not being invoked for _User table

Tags: android, parse-platform

I'm trying to subscribe changes in **_User** table, but when I'm changing somethings in **_User** table `handleEvents` not invoked,here is how I'm doing that:

```
  private var parseLiveQueryClient: ParseLiveQueryClient? = ParseLiveQueryClient.Factory.getClient()
  private var subscriptionHandling: SubscriptionHandling<ParseUser>? = null
  private val livePointQuery = ParseUser.getQuery()

  init {
      subscriptionHandling = parseLiveQueryClient?.subscribe(livePointQuery)
      subscriptionHandling?.handleSubscribe {
        if (it != null){
          Log.e("LIVE_QUERY","success") // invoked successfully 
        }else{
          Log.e("LIVE_QUERY","null")
        }

      subscriptionHandling?.handleEvents { _, event, parseUser ->
        Log.e("LIVE_QUERY_EVENT","${event.name}")
        if(parseUser != null){
          Log.e("LIVE_QUERY",parseUser.objectId)
        }else{
          Log.e("LIVE_QUERY","user null")
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Logcat result:

```
ParseLiveQueryClient: Socket onMessage {"op":"subscribed","clientId":163,"requestId":1}
```

P.S, I'm successfully subscribing other table data updates, ex: Chat.

I have also opened the issue to [parse-community/ParseLiveQuery-Android](https://github.com/parse-community/ParseLiveQuery-Android/issues/97)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solved**! The problem were not in client side code, that was on server side configuration, `_User class` didn't have `LiveQuery` enabled, after enabling I got updates:)